# How do I edit the rtprio limit in Ubuntu through WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm simulating embedded software on my PC due to COVID-19 restricting my team's access to hardware. We are using the uCOS-III RTOS from Micrium, and the Linux POSIX port requires the rtprio limit to be set to unlimited. Their startup guide says to add `<username> - rtprio unlimited` to the `limits.conf` file, which I found in `/etc/security/`. When I try that and then run `ulimit -a`, the limit for `rtprio` is still 0.

I have also tried running `ulimit -r unlimited`, but I don't have the correct permissions unless I'm in a **sudo** bash session. The only way I've found to run the RTOS code properly is to run `sudo bash` and have `ulimit -r unlimited` in the `~/.bashrc`. This requires me to be **sudo** anytime I want to run the executable, which is somewhat annoying and restricts some debugging options as well.

I am currently running this through Windows Subsystem for Linux, which is what I'm assuming is hindering this. I'm on WSL2 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I'm just wondering if there is a way to change the rtprio limit not in superuser mode. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After adding in `/etc/security/limits.conf` something like this:

```
#<domain>           <type>  <item>         <value>
<your_user_name>    hard    rtprio          20
<your_user_name>    soft    rtprio          0
```

Somehow it doesen't directly work when you login and therefore you need to change the user via `su` before using the new limits. Try `su <your_user_name>` before setting the `ulimit`

```
 $ ulimit -r
 0
 $ ulimit -Sr 1
 1
 $ ulimit -r
 1
```

Note that you can set the soft limit between 0 ant the hard limit (0 - 20 in this case) and you can irreversibly reduce the hard limit.